# In Vue 3, how to render a URL as a component?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

Suppose I have an article. It has some sentences and charts. Charts are defined as a link. I want the link to render as component when the page is loaded (Somewhat like the iframe thing).

The closest thing I can think of right now is nested route. But I have uncertain amount of charts, yet I need to define every route with a name, because I'll need uncertain amount of `<router-view name="">` .

Is there any better solution for this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes It's called slugs sometimes

Answer (score 0):

I already find a solution. This can be done by dynamic components.

I use a list of components, and render them one by one with `v-for`. Here's the docs:
https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-dynamic-async.html#dynamic-async-components